# LuaBridge callbacks (passing lua functions to c++)

Tags: c++, binding, lua, luabridge

How do you pass functions from LUA to C++ using Luabridge(1.0.2)

```
local Callback=function()
    print("Inside Callback function!");
end
```

And then pass that callback to c++:

```
self.Background:On("Click",Callback)
```

the "Click" is const std::string&, but how do you define Callback as a function? I've tried a few approaches (void*,std::function) but none of these work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out! If you are trying to pass functions, LuaBridge 2.0 (in development branch) solves this by introducing LuaRef.

Your function would look like this:

```
void DisplayObject::On( const std::string& Param1,LuaRef Param2 );
```

then just call the function like so:

```
Param2();
```

https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge/tree/develop

Comment: LuaRef is now in the master branch of LuaBridge as of mid May 2013.